# Can Cure Wounds do damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ability-scores

Can the Cure Wounds spell deal damage? Say, my spell casting modifier was -2 and I rolled a 1 on the d8. Would the target actually take 1 damage? If so, what kind of damage would it even be?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate and started a bounty on the linked question.

Comment: Anyway, welcome to the site MochaDragon. Take the [tour] when you have a moment. You can find more information about the site at the [help]. Duplicates are not a problem, they can help others find answers, and in this case it pointed us to a question that needed some updated answers.